# Async/await и рекурсивный вызов функции, если !response.ok

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, async-await, fetch

Есть функция, в которой запрос на получение `id` с сервера, `return id` в случае `response.ok` и перезапуск функции, в случае `!response.ok`.

Есть вторая функция, в которой вызов первой функции с присвоением результата переменной.
Далее эта переменная используется при запуске следующей функции.

Проблема в том, что если в первой функции был получен ответ `!response.ok`, то во второй функции `await function` считается выполненным и в переменную записывается `undefined`.

```
async function get_ids (){

    config.body = JSON.stringify({'action':'get_ids'});

    try {
        
        let response = await fetch(host, config);

        if (response.ok) {
            
            console.log('Promise resolved and HTTP status is successful');

            let ids = await response.json();
            ids = ids.result;
            return ids;
    
        } 

        else {
            get_ids();
            console.log('Promise resolved but HTTP status failed - get_ids()');
        }
    }
    catch (error){
        console.error('Promise rejected ' + error);
    }
}
```

Если при первом проходе получили `!response.ok` ...

```
async function main(){

    let ids = await get_ids(); // ... тогда тут будет undefined
    let items = await get_items(ids); // ... и тут ошибка, ids = undefined
}

main();
```

Т.е. перезапуск функции `get_ids` происходит, в случае `!response.ok`, при первом проходе, но в `let ids = await get_ids();` - получим `undefined`, т.к. считается выполненным, хоть и с ошибкой.

---

Пробовал вводить дополнительную функцию проверки, но где-то запутался или оно так не работает, в общем фигня в итоге получилась. В ids опять undefined попадает, хотя вроде как функция проверки выполняется и в процессе в console.log(ids) попадает нормальный результат.

```
async function check_ids(ids){  
    if(ids === undefined){  
        ids = await get_ids();
        check_ids(ids);
    } else {
        return ids;
    }
}
```

и далее в основной функции:

```
let ids = await get_ids();
ids = await check_ids(ids);

console.log(ids); - тут опять undefined
```

---

Можно как-то в этой конструкции:

`if(!response.ok)` сделать `reject`, чтобы во второй функции `await` сработал только в случае ответа `response.ok`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    else {
        console.log('Promise resolved but HTTP status failed - get_ids()');
        return await get_ids();
    }
```

Исправить вашу рекурсию нужно вот так.

Но почему не циклом? Рекурсия выдаст тормоза. Плоский код читается лучше.

Хотя я бы тут делал промис и сеттаймаут.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152176/discussion-on-answer-by-eri-async-await------respo); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.